# How can I toggle a class to an element when clicked?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

Problem: I want to make it so that when I click on a li element, a click event happens and the class "done" is added to it.  I know to do this I need to target all the li's, and a for loop can be used, the only way I've been able to get it to work is by commenting out the code, and creating a new variable to target the class name li, and creating a loop that makes it so it targets all the li items, and adding the "this" thingy, as well as a click event, toggling the class list to done.  But once I tried adding it with the rest of the code, it didn't work.

```js
let button = document.getElementById("button");
let input = document.getElementById("userinput");
let ul = document.querySelector("ul");

function createListElement() {
  let li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
  ul.appendChild(li);
  input.value = "";
}

function addListAfterClick() {
  if (input.value.length > 0) {
    createListElement();
  }
}

button.addEventListener("click", addListAfterClick);
```

```css
.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="userinput">
<button id="button">+</button>
<ul></ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to the `ul` element. If the child element that is clicked [`matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) a list item add a new class to its [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

Adding one listener to a parent element that catches events from its child elements as they "bubble up" the DOM is known as [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/).

```js
const button = document.getElementById('button');
const input = document.getElementById('userinput');
const ul = document.querySelector('ul');

// Add the click listener to the `ul` element
// which calls the `handleClick` handler
ul.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

// Pass in the event to the function, check
// that the clicked element is a list item
// and add a class to it.
function handleClick(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('li')) {
    e.target.classList.add('done');
  }
}

function createListElement() {
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
  ul.appendChild(li);
  input.value = '';
}

function addListAfterClick() {
  if (input.value.length > 0) {
    createListElement();
  }
}

button.addEventListener('click', addListAfterClick);
```

```css
li:hover { cursor: pointer; }
.done { text-decoration: line-through; }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="userinput">
<button id="button">+</button>
<ul></ul>
```

Comment: THANK YOU!  I got really frustrated, but now I can go to bed feeling relieved.

Can you please explain why we need to add "e" from what I know thats Event.

What "target" is,

and why you would use "matches" instead of ===?

THANK YOU

This looks wayyy cleaner and simple than what I was doing, I can see why there are different levels of experience, I can't even do something so simple.

Comment: I just added a link to the documentation for `matches` in the answer. It's been around for a while but doesn't get used that much. It basically checks that [the target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) of the event (ie a child element of `ul`) matches a particular selector, similarly to how you use selectors in `querySelector`. `===` wouldn't work because you'd be trying to compare a DOM object with a string. @PaulinoG and that would always return `false`.

Comment: That `matches` step is important in event delegation. For example: if you had a table but you only wanted to pick up click events from cells - you'd want to avoid all of the other child elements like `thead`, `tbody`, and `tr` so you would do a match only on `td`. Hope that helps.